# Mysql recursive procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, recursion

I have a table name css_diectory with 3 columns directory_id, directory-name and root_directory. I am storing hierarchical directory structure in this table. I have written a procedure to retrieve all the descendants given the directory_id. But it doesn't work. Can anyone please help me.
Here is the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getDescendants
(IN rootId varchar(32), INOUT desecendantsFolderId varchar(3200))
   BEGIN
   DECLARE endOfRecord INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE folderId varchar(32) DEFAULT "";
   DECLARE folderName varchar(32) DEFAULT "";
   DECLARE folderCursor CURSOR FOR   
   Select directory_id, directory_name from css_directory where root_directory=rootId;

   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET endOfRecord = 1;
   OPEN folderCursor;
getFolderId: LOOP
             FETCH folderCursor INTO folderId, folderName;
             IF endOfRecord = 1 THEN 
             LEAVE getFolderId;
             END IF;
             Call getDescendants(folderId,desecendantsFolderId);
            SET desecendantsFolderId = CONCAT(folderId,",",desecendantsFolderId);
            call getDescendants(folderId,desecendantsFolderId);
END LOOP getFolderId;
END
```

Edit: The output of this procedure is always a null set. It does not produce any error

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't work."  Also, you might check what looks like a typo in "flderId" near the end.

Comment: Its not was just a typing error. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I follow what you're doing, but it looks like there's a problem here:

```
SET desecendantsFolderId = CONCAT(folderId,",",desecendantsFolderId);
```

When any argument to `CONCAT()` is null, then the return value is null.  Presumably descendantsFolderId is initially null, and if so, I don't see where that would change.

There are several ways to remedy this, but here is one of them:

```
SET desecendantsFolderId = NULLIF(CONCAT_WS(",",folderId,desecendantsFolderId),"");
```

`CONCAT_WS()` is like `CONCAT()`, except the first argument is used as a separator amd null arguments beyond the first one are disregarded, and empty string is returned if all subsequent arguments are null.  NULLIF() is probably not technically needed, based on the rest of the code, but will ensure that the final result of `CONCAT_WS()` will be turned back to null if the input args are indeed all null.